# klibc-utils : Depends: libklibc (= 2.0.4-2) but 2.0.4-9 is to be installed

Tags: apt, dpkg

*Warning occurred after trying to install packages* `sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev`

```
libffi-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
klibc-utils : Depends: libklibc (= 2.0.4-2) but 2.0.4-9 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

*after entering `apt-get -f install` got below error*

```
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/klibc^i-t' with
  different file '/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/klibc', not allowed <br/>
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/klibc-utils_2.0.4-9_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/klibc to /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/klibc^i-t by klibc-utils', none removed. 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/klibc-utils_2.0.4-9_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should provide more context. The versions involved are from jessie (Debian 8) and stretch (Debian 9). So were you trying to mix versions? to do a dist-upgrade? ... If you did something special nobody can know you did, explain what you did.

Comment: Hi, really good point here. The error was observed after I tried to update from Jessie to Stretch. The goal is to fully upgrade to Debian 9 and ultimately upgrade to Debian 10 when there is no more errors.

May I ask where did you get the clue indicating OS version?

Comment: You can check packages at https://packages.debian.org/ . If you choose distribution any, you'll find the two versions and distributions involved. If you happen to have both sources versions (which you most certainly have while dist-upgrading) you can do `apt-cache policy klibc-utils` to have the same information and deduce the same.

Comment: I don't really know how to give you a certain help. It's certainly possible to force things and ignore the problems, but the result will probably be a system that doesn't boot anymore if nothing is done after (to be sure to reinstall a bootable initramfs). In such case it would require to use the stretch installation in rescue mode to get it back.

Comment: How did you run the upgrade from jessie to stretch? I would expect something like `apt-get -t stretch dist-upgrade` or `apt -t stretch full-upgrade` was done.